# Select query with unique random numer

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to create an SQL statement to select all my data from a table (about 5000 entries) and to assign to each row a unique random number (between 100000 and 999999).

How can I ensure that each random number is unique?

If I try something like

```
SELECT pid, FLOOR(RAND() * (999999 - 100000 + 1)) + 100000 as 'RanNum' FROM mytable
```

and check (e.g in Excel), at least some RanNum are duplicates. How can I prevent this in a query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the only "easy" way to do this in a single query is to partition the range and produce one number per range.  Something like this:

```
select t.*,
       floor(rand() * (range / @rn) + 1 + 100000 + (rn - 1) * (range / @rn))
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum,
             (999999 - 100000) as range
      from mytable t
      -- order by rand()
     ) t;
```